# Applying function using dplyr and setting output as columns in dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr

I have a huge dataframe and I am applying a function that has multiple outputs on one column and would like to add these outputs as columns in the dataframe.

Example function:

```
measure <- function(x){ # useless function for illustrative purposes
     one <- x+1
     two <- x^2
     three <- x/2
     m <- c(one,two,three)
     names(m) <- c('Plus1','Square','Half')
     return(m)
 }
```

My current method which is very inefficient:

```
a <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% mutate(Plus1 = measure(wt)[1], Square = measure(wt)[2], 
       Half = measure(wt)[3]) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Output:

```
head(a,15)

    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb Plus1 Square  Half
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  3.62  3.875 4.215
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  3.62  3.875 4.215
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  3.32  4.190 4.150
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  3.62  3.875 4.215
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  4.44  4.570 5.070
6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  3.62  3.875 4.215
7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4  4.44  4.570 5.070
8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2  3.32  4.190 4.150
9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2  3.32  4.190 4.150
10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4  3.62  3.875 4.215
11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4  3.62  3.875 4.215
12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3  4.44  4.570 5.070
13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3  4.44  4.570 5.070
14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3  4.44  4.570 5.070
15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4  4.44  4.570 5.070
```

Is there any more efficient way to do this? My actual function has 13 outputs and it is taking very long to apply to my large dataframe. Please help!

Comment: If you want more efficient way just use `data.table`: 1. `return` from `measure` - `data.frame(Plus1 = one, square = two, Half = three)`; 2. Load library -`library(data.table)`; 3. Make sure that your data is a `data.table` - `d <-data.table(mtcars)`; 4. Calculate - `d[, measure(wt), cyl]`. If you prefer pipe you can use this - ``library(magrittr); d %>% cbind(.[, measure(wt), cyl])``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be various ways to solve this however, one option is to return a `tibble` output from the function, `split` the dataframe based on group, calculate the statistics for each and bind the result together.

```
library(tidyverse)

measure <- function(x){
   tibble(Plus1 = x+1,Square = x^2,Half = x/2) 
}


bind_cols(mtcars %>% arrange(cyl), 
          mtcars %>% 
              group_split(cyl) %>% 
              map_df(~measure(.$wt)))

#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb Plus1    Square   Half
#1  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 3.320  5.382400 1.1600
#2  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 4.190 10.176100 1.5950
#3  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 4.150  9.922500 1.5750
#4  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1 3.200  4.840000 1.1000
#5  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2 2.615  2.608225 0.8075
#6  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 2.835  3.367225 0.9175
#....
```

This calls `measure` only once per group irrespective of number of values returned unlike in the attempt it was called `n` times to extract `n` values.